# PHP session is empty jquery ajax

Tags: php

I have moved my site to a new hosting where PHP is 5.3.23.

Now when I call a page with ajax, it do not have a session.

```
<?php
session_start();

var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

session returns nothing.

Comment: Show your ajax request code

Answer (score 1):

You should specify some session parameters before you want to print them

Also, `var_dump()` function always displays null for $_SESSIONS. Use

```
 Print_r ($_SESSION);
```

Comment: Session parameters have been already specified, but 
print_r($_SESSION); shows Array ( ).